# Duplicar registro con nuevo Id y otro campo personalizado

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una base de datos (`basedatos`) y una tabla (`contratos`) con los siguientes campos:

```
Id
Nombre
Fecha  (timestamp)
Vendedor
Telefono
Gestionado
```

Quiero insertar en una página php un botón que me duplique el registro pero con el Id consecutivo, la fecha es timestamp y que en el campo `nombre` me concatene el valor que ya tiene con *R*. Es decir, si el campo `nombre` originalmente es "Pedro", ahora el nuevo registro será "Pedro *R*".

He intentado:

```
INSERT INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) 
  SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE CAMPO=VALOR
```

pero no veo cómo concatena.

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que has intentado, en que has fallado, que errores te ha dado, muestranos tu código para poder ayudarte. Pasate por el [tour] y por [ask] y edita tu pregunta

Comment: pues es que en esto estoy perdido,he visto algo como esto:

INSERT INTO TABLA1 (CAMPO1, CAMPO2)
SELECT CAMPO1, CAMPO2 FROM DUAL WHERE CAMPO=VALOR

pero no veo  como concatenar

Comment: Deberias intentar que has hecho con PHP, te has conectado a la base de datos?

Comment: si, la coneccion no es problema

Comment: Pues entonces, adjunta tu PHP en la pregunta.

Comment: Pues gracias por la ayuda, entiendo las normas de la página pero algunos de nosotros no somos ingenieros, he intentado algo pero no hace lo que necesito, entonces ¿para que lo pongo?

Comment: Para que podamos ver donde esta el erro

Comment: pues gracias por la no ayuda

Comment: Pedro, lo que indica @Andoni considero que va en la dirección correcta. Si no muestras lo que has intententado, puede que respondamos con código que ya tienes y estemos malgastando esfuerzos. Mostrar el punto en el que estás es de ayuda para tener más claro cómo lo estás haciendo, dónde estás encallado, etc. También es práctico mostrar un [mcve]. Gracias por tu visita, seguro que entre todos podemos hacer que esto funcione.

Comment: Por otra parte, no queda claro si tu duda es la parte PHP o MySQL.

Comment: Pedro, como a dicho @fedorqui necesitamos un ejemplo, saber que estas haciendo, estoy intentando ayudarte para que mejores tu pregunta y asi poder entender mejor que es lo que te falla para poder solucionarlo.

Comment: Ojo que puedes tener un problema con esa funcionalidad, pues si duplicas con el id siguiente y ya existiese ese id y sea clave te va a denegar la insercion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La consulta que tienes es un buen punto de partida.

El problema es que no encuentras cómo concatenar " R" al resultado. Para ello puedes usar [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) <sub>(en inglés)</sub> de la siguiente forma:

```
INSERT INTO `contratos` (nombre, id)
  SELECT
     CONCAT(nombre, ' R'), id + 1
  FROM
     contratos
  WHERE
     nombre = "Pedro"
```

Fíjate en que estamos haciendo `` INSERT INTO `nombre_de_tabla` (campos, a, insertar) `` pues apenas insertamos dos.

Nótese que esta respuesta aborda el problema a nivel MySQL. A nivel PHP habría que hacer otras cosas, pero para ello necesitamos ver en qué punto estás.

Comment: @Mariano ¡gracias por la indicación! La verdad es que no me acordaba, genial que me refrescaras lo de usar triple ` para marcar una comilla invertida dentro de un código :)

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta dada por @fedorqui es correcta, siempre y cuando el id no sea autoincremental y al sumarle 1 al id actual podrías generar una key duplicada con otro registro.

```
INSERT INTO `contratos` (nombre)
  SELECT
     CONCAT(nombre, ' R')
  FROM
     contatos
  WHERE
     id = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que solo agregando el campo ID y en el select el valor NULL ya deberia incrementar el ID:

```
 INSERT INTO TABLA1 (ID,CAMPO1, CAMPO2) 
  SELECT null,CAMPO1, CAMPO2
  FROM DUAL
  WHERE CAMPO=VALOR
```

Comment: No exactamente, el OP quiere el id consecutivo pero si id es autoincremental te va a poner la siguiente al ultimo, el cual no tiene porque ser el seleccionado. Si id no es autoincremental el resultado puede ser error o el valor por defecto.